# How to Detect/List multiply display in ubuntu using python?

Tags: python, display

I want to list if multiply displays are available in Ubuntu/Debian using python3 (if a display is connected to ubuntu with VGA or HDMI), or when an external display connected detect.

I don't have any idea to do that if everyone has any way please help me.

Comment: I assume "multiply" means multiple here. One simple approach can be, `import os` and run `lshw -C video`.

Comment: my propose was external display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to parse `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

The displays sections start with `EDID for output`

```
[    11.189] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output eDP-1
[    11.191] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[    11.206] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output HDMI-1
[    11.206] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-2
[    11.218] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output HDMI-2
[    11.231] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1-1
[    11.244] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1-2
[    11.244] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1-3
```

In this example eDP-1 and DP-1-1 is the laptop display, DP-1 and DP-1-2 is one monitor over display port and DP-2 and DP-1-3 is the other.  The output between each EDID entry is the detailed monitor information:

```
[    11.231] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: a07b  Serial#: XXXXXXXX
[    11.231] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2013  Week: 27
[    11.231] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.4
[    11.231] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[    11.231] (II) modeset(0): 8 bits per channel
[    11.231] (II) modeset(0): Digital interface is DisplayPort
```

Another example:

```
[     6.893] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-0
[     6.952] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output HDMI-0
[     6.983] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DVI-0
[     6.998] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DVI-1
```

As you can see, the naming conventions are not consistent as my laptop has an EDID for each port and one for each screen, where my desktop does not.

Answer (score -1):

You can seek for the /proc/fb system file. This is a frame-buffer proc system file that summarizes your actual video adapters.

Within python3, simply, open this system file and read the results:

```
fd = open("/proc/fb", "r")
printf(fd.readline())
```

assuming you have only one adapter connected:

```
$ cat /proc/fb
```

With following result:

```
0 svgadrmfb
```

This the results you will get!

Comment: How does this answer the question?  What does `0 svgadrmfb` mean?